# htaccess and PHP handler

Tags: php, .htaccess

My shared hosting provider uses PHP 5.2.x. When I contacted them to ask why, and if 5.3.X was available, they said that they maintain 5.2.x so that client scripts don't break, but offer "A handler for PHP 5.3 is added to our shared and reseller servers for those who wish to utilize it."

I was instructed to "add the following code to your .htaccess file:

```
Action application/x-hg-php53 /cgi-sys/php53
AddType application/x-hg-php53 .php
```

is it as simple as adding that to my site's root .htaccess file? And then everything will automatically use their 5.3 PHP instead of the default 5.2?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: because I'd rather not bring down my site by accident because I was fumbling around with .htaccess without knowing a darn thing about .htaccess -- I have users to worry about besides myself! :-)

Comment: This will use CGI: it will start a new `php53` process for each request. This is somewhat slower than `mod_php`.

Comment: If you worry about breaking stuff, you should test that your scripts work with PHP 5.3 first :)

Comment: My scripts are coded to 5.3 spec on my development box. I was afraid I'd honk the .htaccess edit and screw something up. :-)

Comment: @Andrew I wasn't suggesting you try it out on your live site. Setup a separate app under a new directory and try it out with a simple `<?php echo phpversion() ?>`

Comment: That makes more sense, yes! (laugh) +1 to you sir, x2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is: These two lines instruct the server to associate any file ending with ".php" to call a specific program, namely php53.

Give it a try!

You could even write

```
AddType application/x-hg-php53 .php53
```

to make the "old" PHP execute *.php files, while your *.php53 files will be executed by PHP 5.3.x

> The exact option depends on your hosting. For example this is the correct way to do it for [1&1](https://www.1and1.com/):
>
> AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be. I have done this before, but to get an old site to use PHP4 because lots of things broke in PHP5 (it was an ancient site).

Once you add it to your `.htaccess`, you can confirm the version with `echo PHP_VERSION` or simply inspect the `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Action`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_actions.html#action) directive needs [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in the site configuration to include `FileInfo`. Otherwise you'll get Internal Server Errors.

Since this is shared hosting, and since they told you to do it, it probably is set up this way. If `RewriteRule` works, then it is set up this way.